# Reactor Flux<String> one to many Flux<T>

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive, reactor

I currently have a flux which results from some async operations and produces `Flux<String>`. I would like to then use those strings as params in a legacy callback API that will result in multiple events emitted per input String from the primary flux.

The following code works as expected, but I cant find a way to terminate successfully the second flux without doing seemingly hacky things like keeping counters and such. Is there a more idiomatic way to do that?

```
    public Flux<Account> getAccounts(UUID userId) {
        var tokens = tokenRepo.findAllActiveByAccountUUID(userId);

          return tokens.flatMap(p -> Flux.create(e -> {
            var r = new AccountsGetRequest().accessToken(p);
            c.accountsGet(r).enqueue(new Callback<>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<AccountsGetResponse> call,
                                       @NotNull Response<AccountsGetResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        (response.body()).forEach(e::next);
                        e.complete();
                    } else {
                        log.debug(response.toString());
                        e.error(new RuntimeException("getAccounts" + response.code()));
                        e.complete();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<AccountsGetResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                    e.error(t);
                    e.complete();
                }
            });
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call [`e.complete()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/SynchronousSink.html#complete--) after the `forEach`

I think it would be simpler to use `Flux.fromIterable(response.body())` instead of `Flux.generate`

Note that if `c.accountsGet(r)` is a blocking call, you should probably use the `publishOn` operator to switch to another scheduler to prevent blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, that worked. A couple of additional questions / comments. `accountsGet` is a legacy async API based on okHTTP, so I'm using the Flux.create to glue the async callback to the stream APIs. I used generate before but it wont work since response body contains multiple items so I cant use a SyncSink, I had to change it to Flux.create. I believe the onResponse and onError manage their own thread execution models. Basically is the above the idiomatic way to stich a one -> many response coming from a legacy future callback?

Comment: As I said in my answer, `c.accountsGet(r)` is an async blocking call, so you need to switch to another [`Scheduler`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#parallel--). Based on the documentation I would use `Schedulers.elastic()` -> `tokens.scheduleOn(Schedulers.elastic()).flatMap(...)`. Like I said, I think it's simpler to user `Flux.fromIterable` and `Flux.error` instead of using `Flux.create`.

Comment: `tokens.publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).flatMap(...)` instead of `scheduleOn`

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand. What was meant by async blocking. The acountsGet already is executed in its own pool and doesnt return anything so where would the fromIterable be called and returned. Im looking at the canonical example on how to plug an callback based async API into a flux. Could yo maybe share a snippet ? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71656428/reactor-fluxstring-one-to-many-fluxt/71659803?noredirect=1#comment126672384_71659803